# Mongodb connection refused for remote connection

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDb version 3.0, I can connect through shell prompt but I cant connect through Studio3T for MongoDb ,
i am getting the following error

[Connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isofc.png)

Comment: have you tried to connect to mongoDB using terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs received from MongoDB running on Windows Server 2012 :

*WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip  to specify which IP addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.*

I've solved it adding adding **--bind_ip_all** in the registry at 
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MongoDB* and restarting the MongoDB service.

Final windows service string:
*D:\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe --logpath D:\data\db\mongodb.log --logappend --dbpath  D:\data\db --port --service --bind_ip_all --auth*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to connect to mongodb on a remote server.  In this case you need to use the SSH Tunnel option.  Basically you need to tell Studio3T that it firstly has to connect to the remote server, and then to connect to MongoDB on that server.  What you are currently trying to do is connect to the remote server on port 27017, but the server will not expose this port externally.  You need to connect to the server via ssh first (port 22?) then open the mongod connection (port 27107).  If you could post information about how you have connected with the shell prompt that would help confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

Open services app in windows.Select MongoDB.There you can see that your mongo db server is stopped.Start it.Then come to cmd and start mongo db.Now it works.